# Flutter pdfx PlatformException(RENDER_ERROR, Invalid PDF format, null, null) Error

Tags: flutter, dart

I loaded PDF with File Picker and wrote Logic to save PDF Path to Hive.

However, when the app is restarted, 'PdfDocument.openFile' does not work properly with the Path stored in Hive.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKn4J.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H61vJ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUofe.png)

Error Log is "PlatformException(RENDER_ERROR, Invalid PDF format, null, null) Error"

I browsed Stack overflow But I didn't find solution